# Python ImportError: DLL load failed: cannot fine the DLL generated by another computer

Tags: python

In a word, a DLL generated by computer A cannot be referred in computer B.

1. Get HKIPCamera_wrap.cxx using SWIG package:
   (Source files include HKIPcamera.cpp, HKIPcamera.h and HKIPcamera.i)
   Swig -I"D:\Program Files\opencv3\opencv\build\include" -python -c++ HKIPCamera.i
2. Create a DLL project, add the HKIPcamera.h file to the header file, and add HKIPcamera_wrap.cxx,HKIPcamera.cpp to the source file.
3. Rename the generated .dll file to _HKIPcamera.pyd and place it in the same directory of HKIPcamera.py, which I think can be referenced in Python.
4. The computer A that generates the .dll can refer to the module normally, and the .dll then be moved to the computer B.
5. Query dependent DLLs through ’dependecy walker‘ to join but it still can't work...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\HIK_YOLO_Python\HKIPcamera.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/HIK_YOLO_Python/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import HKIPcamera
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\HIK_YOLO_Python\HKIPcamera.py", line 17, in <module>
    _HKIPcamera = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\HIK_YOLO_Python\HKIPcamera.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_HKIPcamera')
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score -1):

fine... it seems that I forgot a directory.